# Color styling for >100 COG GeoTIFF with min/max values in OpenLayers

Tags: colors, openlayers, geotiff

I have this color style (from 0-90 values range) for a COG GeoTIFF file having a values range between 12 (minimum value) and 50 (maximum value):

```
const autominmaxrange = {
  color: [
    'case',
    ['>', ['band', 2], 0],
    [
      'interpolate',
      ['linear'],
      ['band', 1],
      0, [0, 89, 179, 0.01],
      90, [255, 234, 0, 5.0],
    ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
  ],
};
```

However, I have >100 COG GeoTIFF files with different min/max range values. I would like that the min/max values will be auto-recognized for each COG GeoTIFF in a single color style (eg. the one above with a gray color scale), how can this be achieved?

Many thanks for any pointers,

Comment: If the min and max values are in the metadata and you use `normalize: true` band data should be returned in the range 0 to 1

Comment: nice idea, thanks for that, my only problem is that I am getting pixel information, so if I understand well, `event.pixel` won't return the actual GeoTIFF value (float32) but values between 0-1 (int type), is it correct? if so, what can it be done to get the actual data?